# binding data from get parameters angular router

Tags: angular, routerlink

how to get value from parameters in angular routerlink ??

this my code

Component.ts :

```
Hotels: struct_hotel;
id : struct_hotel['id'] 

constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _service: ResultService)
    {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
          let id= params['id'];
          //console.log(id);  
      });
    }
getDetails(id): void {
    this._service.getHotel(this.id).then(Hotels => this.Hotels = Hotels);
}

ngOnInit():void {
    this.getDetails(this.id);
  }
```

Service :

```
private apidetail = 'http://localhost/bobobox/public/api/v1/room/show';
getHotel(id: string ): Promise<struct_hotel>
    {
        const url = `${this.apidetail}/${id}`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as struct_hotel[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

and i call it on html like this `{{Hotels.hotel_name}}` and i got error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hotel_name' of undefined`

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is due to the async call might not be ready before the `ngOnInit` runs.

You need to put the `this.getDetails(this.id);` inside the subscribe in the constructor after reading the params

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      let id= params['id'];
      this.getDetails(this.id);
  });
```

Also there seems to be some inconsistency on the type of object you are trying to use and the one you are getting from the service.

It seems you are passing an `id` to get one hotel so the response should be

```
then(response => response.json() as struct_hotel)
```

Comment: theres no error in console, but still not binding any data. any help ?

Comment: OK to rule out possible origins of the problem try to console.log response.json() and see if you get data.

Comment: there's no data.. then what the next step ?

Comment: Well if there’s no data that’s the origin of your problem. Your API is not returning the data :). You need to check if http get request should be returning data for the id you are passing down.

Comment: im sure my api work correctly or maybe my service is my problem ? 
this the api link public/api/v1/room/show/{id} theres problem with get parameter to link my api ?

Comment: One other thing you seem to be requesting an hotel and your service is pointing to a room in the url. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164242/discussion-between-shaugi-muhammad-and-hugo-noro).

Answer (score 0):

Since your request is asynchronous  use safe navigation operator while binding

```
{{Hotels?.hotel_name}}
```

if Hotels is an array, then you need ngFor as follows,

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataobj of Hotels">
     {{dataobj ?.hotel_name}}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try to console log Hotels, it's probably undefined.

There is a mistake in your code though, you are returning struct_hotel array, and you are Promising struct_hotel (not an array). Which one should it be?

If it's an array, you can't just access it as Hotels.hotel_name, it should be Hotels[i].hotel_name.

Answer (score 0):

Hotels is undefined at first. You must declare with a new class since you set it to a type of struct_hotel.

```
Hotels: struct_hotel = new struct_hotel();
```

After doing this, you may now use properties under that class on your bindings with a default value.